# Solspace Freeform email notifications coming from "unknown sender"

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using Freeform 4.1.4 (the free version) w/ EE 2.8.1.

I have a form with a first name field ({name_first}), a last name field ({name_last}), and an email field ({email}) field, all of which are required. When I created the form's notification, I configured the "From Name" field to use "{name_first} {name_last}" and "From Email" to use "{email}".

In the past, this has always worked: the email notifications used the user-submitted values for the sender info.

However, on this site, the email notifications arrive *but* they come from "unknown sender" (according to Gmail). Everything else about the notifications is fine -- e.g., the message comes through intact -- but the sender info is missing.

On a whim, I tried hardcoding the notification's "From Name" and "From Email" fields so they weren't using user-submitted values, but that didn't fix anything. And I've checked the EE installation's email settings, which are the defaults (AFAIK). Nothing seems out of the ordinary there.

Am I missing something? Did something change in notifications with the new version of Freeform?

Comment: FWIW, I've updated to Freeform 4.1.5 and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Freeform 4.1.4 and 4.1.5. This will be fixed in Freeform 4.1.6 which we are working on now.

If you'd like to patch it yourself in the meantime, in:

```
./system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/libraries/Freeform_notifications.php
```

around line 484, change:

```
$this->variables['from_email']      = $from_name;
```

to:

```
$this->variables['from_email']      = $from_email;
```